# WTSQueryUserToken throws error 1008, even when running under LocalSystem

Tags: windows, windows-services, c++17

I have pretty much the same problem as discussed in [WTSQueryUserToken always throws "An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist" on Windows 7 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621448/wtsqueryusertoken-always-throws-an-attempt-was-made-to-reference-a-token-that-d), but unlike the OP of that question, I'm using C++ on Windows 10 and read the docs properly before starting to code my solution. So my service is most-definitely running under the `LocalSystem` account.

Here's the relevant part of my `SvcInit()` function:

```
    HANDLE hToken;

    // Returns 1, just like in the linked question
    DWORD sessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    if (!WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId, &hToken)) {
        // LogError() takes the name of an error-causing function and calls
        // GetLastError() and FormatMessage() to get the system-defined error
        // message, then logs all of that to a file
        LogError("WTSQueryUserToken");
        return;
    }
```

The docs also mention a need for your service process to have the `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege. The same paragraph that the other question references:

> Obtains the primary access token of the logged-on user specified by the session ID. To call this function successfully, the calling application must be running within the context of the LocalSystem account **and have the SE_TCB_NAME privilege.**

But by reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account, it seems to me as though **any** process running under the `LocalSystem` account would **automatically** have this privilege:

> The LocalSystem account has the following privileges:
>
> - SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME (disabled)
> - SE_AUDIT_NAME (enabled)
> - SE_BACKUP_NAME (disabled)
> - *...many others*
> - **SE_TCB_NAME (enabled)**

So do I need to explicitly add this privilege to my process or not? And what else may be the cause of my issue? MTIA! :-)

Comment: `ERROR_NO_TOKEN` - *The token query is for a session in which no user is logged-on. This occurs, for example, when the session is in the idle state or SessionId is zero.*

Comment: @RbMm Where are you getting that description from? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-, the description of error 1008 is "An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist", which is also what I get from `FormatMessage()` and what the linked question states. But that description doesn't really explain *why* the token doesn't exist, or where I'm supposedly referencing it wrongly. I'll add a code snippet to the question to hopefully provide some more insight.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UcUOPpv.png - better show your relevant code

Comment: or look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069138/how-to-get-token-of-logged-in-user-from-within-windows-service-with-c#comment53997778_33069138

Comment: @RbMm Ahh nice! Would you mind sharing the source of that image (if it's a website)? It seems to have much better error descriptions than the standard MS docs page that I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: this is from very old (2008) offline msdn. in new you can view - *Among other errors, GetLastError can return one of the following errors.* - and than nothing.. part of old content is lost

Comment: @RbMm LOL what a joke...but hey, we're talking about MicroS**t here, so it really doesn't surprise me.

Comment: when you call `WTSQueryUserToken` ? based on what event ?

Comment: @RbMm As I said just above the code snippet, it is taken from the `SvcInit()` function. This is where one generally initialises the service, sets up a stop event and performs the main functionality of the service until the stop event is triggered. So in answer to your second question: it is triggered when my system boots.

Comment: *when my system boots* - this and your error of course. at this time any user not logged in, as result no user token. no user -> no token. error very logical at this place. you need rewrite logic.

Comment: @RbMm OK that makes sense and it had occurred to me before, but could you please explain why I get a seemingly-valid session ID (1) from `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()`? Would it help to use `WTSEnumerateSessions()` (I remember reading about that somewhere on SO when I was looking for a solution to this problem earlier)?

Comment: the *csrss.exe* in session 1, *winlogon.exe* already started. so terminal 1 session already exist. but yet no any logged in users. and simply question - for what you need user token at this time ? if exist several users in system - which concrete user token you think must got ? only this question show error in design. the key question from which you need begin - for what you need some user token ?

Comment: *This occurs, for example, when the session is in the idle state* - this is exactly your case

Comment: Ahh OK, that makes perfect sense, thanks so much! The reason I need a user token is to run another process interactively, and this process needs to run from the moment the PC is turned on until the moment it's turned off...hence my thinking that I need a service. But I'm starting to realise from your comments and many others on SO that I should probably just run my interactive process as a scheduled task.

Comment: you anyway need wait until some user logged in. in service, inside *HandlerEx* routine you got session notifications - `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` - look say for `WTS_SESSION_LOGON` and in `PWTSSESSION_NOTIFICATION` you will be have `dwSessionId`.

Comment: OK thanks. If you write up your comments as a proper answer I'll gladly accept it, since you very-much deserve the rep ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in current [`WTSQueryUserToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken) exist incomplete phrase:

> *Among other errors, **GetLastError** can return one of the following*
> *errors.*

but in old msdn was list or errors which can return api:

[image]

so `ERROR_NO_TOKEN` mean can be returned if

> *The token query is for a session in which no user is logged-on. This*
> *occurs, for example, when the session is in the idle state or*
> *SessionId is zero.*

if we try get user token at system startup time of course yet no any logged in user. user simply is unknown and as result not exist and user token (say token containing user sid - but user and unknown, sid is unknown, token can not exist at this time). however service if want can start process exactly when some (any)user logon to system. this need do from
[`HandlerEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lphandler_function_ex) callback which registered via `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx`

we need look for `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` event.
simply code for run process in user session can be like this

```
DWORD WINAPI HandlerEx(
                       DWORD dwControl,
                       DWORD dwEventType,
                       PVOID lpEventData,
                       PVOID lpContext
                       )
{

    switch (dwControl)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE:

        if (dwEventType == WTS_SESSION_LOGON)
        {
            HANDLE hToken;
            if (WTSQueryUserToken(reinterpret_cast<PWTSSESSION_NOTIFICATION>(lpEventData)->dwSessionId, &hToken))
            {
                PVOID lpEnvironment;
                if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(&lpEnvironment, hToken, FALSE))
                {
                    STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };
                    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
                    if (CreateProcessAsUserW(hToken, 
                        L"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, lpEnvironment, 0, &si, &pi))
                    {
                        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                    }
                    DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment);
                }
                CloseHandle(hToken);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome write up! Thanks again :D

Comment: Hi again, I've updated my code to handle SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE but it seems that code is never executed...any ideas why? My code is almost identical to [The Complete Service Sample](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/the-complete-service-sample) on MSDN, but I've changed `gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP` to `gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE` in `ReportSvcStatus()`, updated `SvcCtrlHandler()` to match your code and added my own code that shouldn't effect anything to `SvcInit()`. What gives?!

Comment: @Kenny83 - this code call `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler` for `SvcCtrlHandler` but you need use RegisterServiceCtrlHandler**Ex** use - read this [*This parameter can also be one of the following extended control codes. Note that these control codes are not supported by the Handler function.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lphandler_function_ex)

Comment: @Kenny83 only Handler**Ex** received `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` notification.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I've changed that too (it was pretty much the first change I made to MSFT's code).

Comment: @Kenny83 - i not have your code, not view it. as result can not say why. but can say code which i paste here - not simply code, but tested in service and it worked - receiver notification when user log in locally or via rdp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224196/discussion-between-kenny83-and-rbmm).